# Is my emoji dry?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, parsing

This is my pet emoji, Billy:

```
-_-
```

Emojis don't like to be in the rain, so Billy is sad... Let's draw him an umbrella to make him feel better!

```
  /\
 /  \
/    \

  -_-
```

This is good, he is entirely covered by his umbrella! Here is an example where only part of him is covered:

```
  /\
 /  \
/    \

     -_-
```

In this case, sections 2 and 3 of his body are exposed to the rain.

Umbrellas come in many shapes and sizes, but they're always made up from a series of ascending slashes `/` followed by a series of descending backslashes `\`. For example, these are all valid umbrellas:

```
  /\
 /  \
/    \

/\

    /\
   /  \
  /    \
 /      \
/        \
```

And these are not:

```
/   \

\/

  \
 / \
/   \

 0\
/  \

//\\
/  \
```

You need to determine which parts of my emoji are exposed to the rain.

## Clarifications

- Your program (or function) will take a 2d string as input. This can be in whatever format is most convenient or natural to your language. An array of strings, an array of arrays of characters, a string with newlines in it etc.
- You must output which sections of the emoji are exposed to the rain. This can be zero-indexed or one-indexed, as long as you make this clear. Output can be in any reasonable format. If the entire emoji is protected from the rain, output nothing (or an empty array).
- You can assume that all inputs will have a valid umbrella, and the same emoji: `-_-`. The emoji will always be on the last line of the input, however their might be several empty lines between the umbrella and the emoji.
- Everything that isn't part of the umbrella or the emoji will be a space   character or newline.
- The input will be padded with spaces so that the length of each line is the same.

Standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Test IO:

All of the sample cases will use one-indexing.

```
  /\
 /  \
/    \

  -_-

Outputs: []

----------------

   /\
  /  \

     -_-

Outputs: [2, 3]

----------------

    /\
   -_-

Outputs: [1]

----------------

     /\
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
 /        \
/          \




               -_-

Outputs: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Can we output the parts of the emoji that are in the rain? i.e. `["_","-"]`.

Comment: If our language supports strings, can we still accept a 2D array of characters? For example, Array in JavaScript has different functions available to it than String does.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, that is acceptable.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ No, you should output the numbers.

Comment: I think you mean emoticon.  Dry emoji would be  (or ☂️ I suppose)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

Code:

```
|…-_-123:)ø€J€ï
```

Explanation:

```
|                  # Take all input as a list of strings.
 …-_-              # 3-char string, which results into "-_-".
     123:)         # Replace "-_-" with 123.
          ø        # Zip, resulting into the columns of the 2D array.
           €J      # Join each of them.
             €ï    # For each, convert to integer. If this is not possible, it will ignore
                     the result.
                   # Implicitly output the array.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=fOKApi1fLTEyMzopw7jigqxK4oKsw68&input=ICAgICAvXCAgICAgICAKICAgIC8gIFwgICAgICAKICAgLyAgICBcICAgICAKICAvICAgICAgXCAgICAKIC8gICAgICAgIFwgICAKLyAgICAgICAgICBcICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAtXy0) (make sure to pad *all* lines with spaces to the same length..

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 95 bytes

```js
a=>[...a[n=0]].map((_,i)=>a.map(s=>(c=s[i])>"-"&c<"_"?p=1:n+=!++c,p=0)|p<!c&&o.push(n),o=[])&&o
```

Input should be an array of strings, with each line padded with spaces to form a square. Output is an array of 1-indexed numbers.

### Explanation

```js
var solution =

a=>
  [...a[n=0]].map((_,i)=>  // n = current index of emoji, for each column i of input
    a.map(s=>              // for each line s
      (c=s[i])             // c = character in column
      >"-"&c<"_"?p=1       // p = 1 if column is protected from rain
      :n+=!++c,            // increment n if emoji character found, c = 1 if last line
                           // contained a space in the current column
      p=0
    )
    |p<!c&&o.push(n),      // if the emoji is not protected in the current column
    o=[]
  )
  &&o
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="6" cols="40">   /\   
  /  \  
        
     -_-</textarea><br />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value.split('\n'))">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>20</s> 19 bytes (non-competing)

```
G^R123?/
f\GddHÍó
```

Alternate, competing version (21 bytes):

```
G^R123?/
f\òjòddHÍó
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=OnNlIG5vc29sCkdeUjEyMxs_LwoWZlxHZGRIw43Dsw&input=ICAgIC9cCiAgIC1fLQ) (Note, tryitonline.net uses a slightly old version of V. To compensate for this, it uses this slightly longer version)

Explanation:

```
G^          "Move to the first non-whitespace character on the last column
  R123<esc> "Replace the emojii with '123'

?/          "Move backwards to the last '/' character
  <C-v>     "Start a blockwise selection
       f\G  "Move the selection to the next '\', and then to the last line
d           "Delete the block selection
 dH         "Delete the umbrella
```

This alone produces the correct result in 17 bytes. However, it also creates some extra whitespace. I don't mind it, but I don't want to give myself an unfair advantage, so I'm adding two bytes:

```
Íó          "Remove all whitespace
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```
a=>a.map(s=>s.replace(/\S/g,(c,i)=>c>'-'&c<'_'?u[i]=3:++n&u[i]||r.push(n)),n=0,u=[],r=[])&&r
```

Accepts a ragged array of lines and returns a 1-indexed result. Explanation:

```
a=>a.map(               Loop through all lines
 s=>s.replace(/\S/g,    Loop through all non-whitepsace
  (c,i)=>c>'-'&c<'_'    If it's part of the umbrella
   ?u[i]=3              Mark that column as dry
   :++n&                Add 1 to the emoji index
     u[i]||             If the column is not dry
      r.push(n)         Add the emoji index to the result
  ),n=0,u=[],r=[]       Initialise variables
 )&&r                   Return result
```

Answer (score 3):

### Java 8 lambda, <s>241</s> <s>218</s> <s>201</s> <s>191</s> <s>185</s> 184 (or 161) characters

Because ya know, also Java needs dry emojis.

```
import java.util.*;f->{int e,i=e=-1,c,l=f.length-1;while(++e<f[l].length&&f[l][e]!=45);List p=new Stack();l:for(;++i<3;){for(char[]r:f)if((c=r[e+i])==47|c==92)continue l;p.add(i);}return p;}
```

It returns <s>an ArrayList</s> a HashSet a Stack containing the parts of the emoji which are exposed to the rain (indexing starts at 0). The whole thing unwrapped:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q82668 {
    static List isEmojiDryRevE(char[][] fieldToCheck) {
        int emojiStart, i = emojiStart = -1, j, rows = fieldToCheck.length - 1;

        while (++emojiStart < fieldToCheck[rows].length && fieldToCheck[rows][emojiStart] != 45)
            ;

        List parts = new Stack();
        emojiLoop: for (; ++i < 3;) {
            for (j = -1; ++j < rows;) {
                if (fieldToCheck[j][emojiStart + i] > 46) {
                    // umbrella part found
                    continue emojiLoop;
                }
            }
            // no umbrella part found
            parts.add(i);
        }
        return parts;
    }
}
```

---

**Updates**

I did some basic golfing. This includes putting the declarations together, compare with the ascii values to save some characters and shorten the loops.

Thanks to @user902383 for pointing out my dump mistake using ArrayLists instead of just Lists. I replaced the ArrayLists/Lists with HashSets/Sets which saves some more characters. Also thanks for his tip to use a foreach loop in the inner loop! Through that change I am able to create a variable for the index of the last grid row which shortens it a bit more. Overall 17 characters have been saved!

@KevinCruijssen suggested to remove the generics in the initialization, I went one step further: Remove all the generics. This saves another 10 characters.

I switched back from the foreach loop to the for loop. This makes it possible to skip comparing the last line which in turn allows me to shorten the comparison of the ascii values. In this context only '/', '\' and '_' have an ascii value over 46. If we don't check the last line we can use a `> 46 check` instead to checks for the actual value.

Thanks again to @user902383 for showing me that I use a lambda and can use List+Stack instead of Set+HashSet to shave off another character.

---

**String returning version**

@user902383 pointed out I can instead just create a String with the digits. This sounds very cheaty but others seem to solve it this way so here is a shorter version using a String return:

```
f->{int e,i=e=-1,c,r=f.length-1;while(++e<f[r].length&&f[r][e]!=45);String p="";l:for(;++i<3;){for(char[]o:f)if((c=o[e+i])==47|c ==92)continue l;p+=i;}return p;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public class Q82668 {
    public static String isEmojiDryRevD(char[][] fieldToCheck) {
        int emojiStart, i = emojiStart = -1, c, rows = fieldToCheck.length - 1;

        while (++emojiStart < fieldToCheck[rows].length && fieldToCheck[rows][emojiStart] != 45)
            ;

        String parts = "";
        emojiLoop: for (; ++i < 3;) {
            for (char[] row : fieldToCheck) {
                if ((c = row[emojiStart + i]) == 47 | c == 92) {
                    // umbrella part found
                    continue emojiLoop;
                }
            }
            // no umbrella part found
            parts += i;
        }
        return parts;
    }
}
```

Comment: you broke rule number 1 `always program to an interface`,  if you use `List` instead `ArrayList` you can save 5 bytes

Comment: I think inner for loop could be replaced by foreach loop which should give you additional couple of bytes

Comment: So I deleted my last comment, as I thought this was an answer to another question... You're absolutely right, how could I do that wrong :O I'll change it in the next couple minutes.

Comment: As nowhere is specified output has to be a number, and `i` has single digit values, you could change your function to output you string instead array. it sounds reasonable, and it could save you lot od bytes

Comment: @user902383 It sounds very cheaty, but others seem to do it just like that so I'll add a version which uses strings.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but `=new HashSet<>();` can most likely be golfed to `=new HashSet();`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the compiler produces a warning, so it is possible, but is it allowed?

Comment: @Frozn Why wouldn't it be allowed? I know the compiler produces a warning, which happens a lot during code-golfing. What I'm not sure of is if your code still works the same, haven't tested it. If it does, than removing the `<>` saves you 2 bytes. :)

Comment: in your longer solution if you change `Set` back to `List` and use `Stack` as implementation, you could save 1 byte

Comment: @user902383 I don't get that improvement... It still has the same length with Stack as the Set version

Comment: @Frozn im not sure ,`Set p=new HashSet();` seems is longer than `List p=new Stack();` to me

Comment: @user902383 yes, but I also need to change the return value. It is `Set`(3), `Set`(3) and `HashSet`(7) with a total length of 13 against `List`(4), `List`(4) and `Stack`(5) also 13 characters long. Good idea though...

Comment: @Frozn you would be right in good old java, but now we have lambda, and in lambda notation you don't specify type. hence you have `Set(3)` `HashSet(7)` against `List`(4) and `Stack`(5).

Comment: @user902383 Of course! That's what happens if you forget you write a lambda... I always write the function in the ungolfed version and then golf this into a lambda and the method of course needs a return type. Silly me!

Comment: @Frozn not sure did you realized, but i think you didn't updated your golfed versions

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>117</s> 112 bytes

```
s=>s.map(r=>r.map((c,i)=>~'-_'[o='indexOf'](c)&&!s.some(a=>~'/\\'[o](a[i]))?i-r[o]('-'):-1)).pop().filter(n=>~n)
```

Accepts a ragged array of <s>strings</s> [arrays of characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82668/is-my-emoji-dry/82917#comment202118_82668), and returns 0-indexed results.

```
s=>s.map(     // for each row
  r=>         // row
    r.map(    // for each character
      (c,i)=> // character, index
        ~'-_'[o='indexOf'](c) // if character is part of emoji
        &&                    // and
        !s.some(              // none of the rows have umbrella in this column
          a=>~'/\\'[o](a[i])
        )
        ? // then return 0-index of emoji
          i-r[o]('-')
        : // else return -1
          -1
  )
)
.pop()         // get last element of string array
.filter(n=>~n) // filter out -1s
```

### Demo

```js
f=s=>s.map(r=>r.map((c,i)=>~'-_'[x='indexOf'](c)&&!s.some(a=>~'/\\'[x](a[i]))?i-r[x]('-'):-1)).pop().filter(n=>~n)
i.oninput=()=>o.value=f(i.value.split`\n`.map(r=>r.split``))
i.oninput()
```

```html
<textarea rows=6 cols=20 id=i>
   /\
  /  \

     -_-</textarea>
<br/>
<input readonly id=o>
```

Comment: I like your comments!

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 56 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
m`(?<!(?(2)!)^(?<-2>.)*\S(.*¶)+(.)*).(?<=([-_]+))|\D
$.3
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWAoPzwhKD8oMikhKV4oPzwtMj4uKSpcUyguKsK2KSsoLikqKS4oPzw9KFstX10rKSl8XEQKJC4z&input=ICAgICAvXCAgIAogICAgLyAgXCAgCiAgICAgICAtXy0)

This is a single substitution stage, where the regex matches one of the emoji characters, provided that there's a non-space character (i.e. a `/` or `\`) somewhere above in the same horizontal position, and then we capture the number of emoji characters up to that point. This match is replaced with the length of that last capture, which gives us the index of this unsheltered emoji character. The regex also contains a `|\D` to match everything else which gets replaced with nothing at all, so we remove all the other characters.

Comment: Can you explain more how this regex looks above the emoji characters?

Comment: @sintax It uses [balancing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/1633117) to count the characters preceding it on its own line. This measures its horizontal position. Then after I've matched the `/` or ``\``, I'm popping from that group again while matching the stuff preceding *that*, and then make sure I've completely depleted the group. This basically ensures that the horizontal position of the emoji and the roof character match.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> 23 bytes

0-indexed.

```
-m.xsd;.T:R"-_-"s`M3.zd
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-m.xsd%3B.T%3AR%22-_-%22s%60M3.zd&input=%0A+++%2F%5C%0A++%2F++%5C%0A%0A-_-%0A&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
-m.xsd;.T:R"-_-"s`M3.zd

                    .z   all lines of input, as a list
         :R"-_-"s`M3     replace "-_-" by "012" 
                         "012" is generated by s`M3
       .T                transpose, return all columns
                         The sample input becomes:
                           0
                           1
                          /2
                         / 
                         \ 
                         \
 m   d                   for each line:
  .xs                        attempt to convert to integer.
      ;                      if errors, replace to space
-                     d  remove all spaces
```

### History

27 bytes: `` sM:#"^ *\d"0.T:R"-_-"s`M3.z `` ([Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sM%3A%23%22%5E+%2a%5Cd%220.T%3AR%22-_-%22s%60M3.z&input=%0A+++%2F%5C%0A++%2F++%5C%0A%0A-_-%0A&debug=0))

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 43 bytes

```
@(x)find(sum((x(:,x(end,:)~=' '))~=' ')==1)
```

This code finds column positions of non-space characters in the final row of the input, sums the number of non-space characters in those columns, and finds where there's only one such character (the emoji's character, un-shielded by umbrella!). This code only returns proper results for well-formed umbrellas (it assumes any character above our emoji is part of a well-formed umbrella).

Here is a bit of utility code for writing test cases and checking my work:

```
ws = @(x) repmat(' ',1,x);  %  for making strings of spaces
% for writing three-storey umbrellas over an emoji located left-edge at position x
thrht = @(x) strvcat([ws(3) '/\' ws(3); ws(2) '/  \' ws(2); ws(1) '/' ws(4) '\' ws(1); ws(8)], [ws(x-1) '-_-']);
twht = @(x) strvcat([ws(3) '/\' ws(3); ws(2) '/  \' ws(2); ws(8)], [ws(x-1) '-_-']);
```

Running `x = thrht(7)` gives

```
x =

   /\    
  /  \   
 /    \  

      -_-
```

Or 
    `x = twht(0)`
gives

```
x =

   /\   
  /  \  

 -_-
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>114</s> 111 bytes

```
def f(a):c=a.find("\n")+1;r=a.rfind;g=lambda i:([i],[])[r("\\")%c>=r("-")%c-2+i>=r("/")%c];print g(0)+g(1)+g(2)
```

Uses 0 based indexing.

[Try it here](https://repl.it/C1aw/1).

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 31 bytes

```
{(⍳3)∩,(~∨⌿⍵∊'/\')/+\+\'-_-'⍷⍵}
```

This takes a character matrix as input.

Tests:

```
      t1 t2 t3 t4
┌──────┬────────┬──────┬─────────────────┐
│  /\  │   /\   │    /\│     /\          │
│ /  \ │  /  \  │   -_-│    /  \         │
│/    \│        │      │   /    \        │
│      │     -_-│      │  /      \       │
│  -_- │        │      │ /        \      │
│      │        │      │/          \     │
│      │        │      │                 │
│      │        │      │                 │
│      │        │      │                 │
│      │        │      │                 │
│      │        │      │              -_-│
└──────┴────────┴──────┴─────────────────┘
      {(⍳3)∩,(~∨⌿⍵∊'/\')/+\+\'-_-'⍷⍵} ¨ t1 t2 t3 t4
┌┬───┬─┬─────┐
││2 3│1│1 2 3│
└┴───┴─┴─────┘
```

Explanation:

- `'-_-'⍷⍵`: in a matrix of zeroes the size of the input, mark the position of the beginning of `'-_-'` in the input with a 1.
- `+\+\`: Running sum over rows. The first one makes `0 0 0 1 0 0 ...` into `0 0 0 1 1 1 ...`, the second one then makes it into `0 0 0 1 2 3 ...`.
- `⍵∊'/\'`: mark all occurrences of '/' and '\' in the input with 1s.
- `∨⌿`: `or` over columns. This marks with an 1 all positions on the last row that are covered by the umbrella.
- `~`: `not`, because we need the opposite
- `(`...`)/`...: Select all uncovered columns from the running sum matrix from earlier
- `,`: Get a list of all values in the resulting matrix.
- `(⍳3)∩`: Intersection between that and `1 2 3` (this gets rid of any selected 0s or higher values, which would be spaces).